# Find the most frequent triplet in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

We have an array of N numbers. All the numbers are between 1-k.

The problem is how to find the best way of finding the most frequent triplet.

My approach to the problem is:

Say if the input is like { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4}

First search for the count of triplet ( 1, 2, 3) start from the second element in the array till the end of the array. Now we will have the count as 1.
Now start with { 2, 3, 4) and search the array.

for each triplet we scan the array and find the count. Like this we run the array for n-1 times.

This way my algorithm runs in the order of n*n time complexity. Is there any better way for

this problem.?

Comment: What is your definition of `triplet` -- any 3 numbers in sequence, or only any 3 consecutive integers ?  Is `3,4,1` a triplet ?

Comment: what's the space complexity you expected?

Comment: Are you aware of the `triplet` you need or do you intend the algo to find that?

Comment: @bonCodigo: "finding the most frequent triplet"

Comment: +1 for the question :) @Niklas when you said "deterministically" I got the impression you will define all the possible `triplets` then search the max occurance of it..plus how to define a `triplet` was also the other question.. ;)

Comment: @sunmoon You supposed that triplet is 2,3,4! I supposed them as 1,2,3!. I mean that you should determine the rule of the triplet first!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in `O(n * log n)` worst-case space and time complexity: Just insert all triples into a balanced binary search tree and find the maximum afterwards.

Alternatively, you can use a hash table to get `O(n)` expected time (which is typically faster than the search tree approach in reality, if you choose a good hash function).

Answer (score 2):

Are there any memory boundaries i.e. does it run on a device with memory limitations?

If not, maybe this could be good solution:  iterate over array and for each tripple build and representation object (or struct if implemented in c#) which goes into map as a key and the tripple counter as a value.

If you implement `hash` and `equals` functions appropriately, you will be able to find the "most popular" tripple where numbers order matters or not e.g. `1,2,3 != 2,1,3` or `1,2,3 == 2,1,3`

After iterating entire array you would have to find the largest value and its key would be your "*most popular*" tripple. With that approach you could find X most popular tripples too. Also you would scan array only once and aggregate all the trippels (no extra scanning for each tripple).